# php variable with numbers and white spaces echoing incorrectly

Tags: php, numbers, echo, whitespace

I have a page with this global on it:

```
$sampleIssue = array('vol'=>25,'no'=>3 and 4);
```

on another page, I have this code which returns a 1 -????  What is wrong?  I am sure it is something simple, but i am new enough to php not to know.  I have searched white spaces in variables and strings, but still can't find the answer.

```
echo $sampleIssue['no'];
```

Comment: `3 and 4` is true, `"3 and 4"` is `3 and 4`

Comment: [PHP Logical Operators](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$sampleIssue = array('vol'=>25,'no'=>3 and 4);
```

to

```
$sampleIssue = array('vol'=>25,'no'=>'3 and 4');
```

**"3 and 4" is a string. You have to put it with in quotes. 25 will not show any problem because it is a number**

Answer (score 1):

```
$sampleIssue = array('vol'=>25,'no'=>3 and 4);
```

You need some quotes around 3 and 4, like

```
$sampleIssue = array('vol'=>25,'no'=>'3 and 4');
```

The expression `3 and 4` without quotes evaluates to *Are both the number 3 and the number 4 "true"*?, which itself is true. If you echo out a PHP boolean true, it displays as "1".